# How to call a method using navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have pushed a view in navigation controller. For eg: view1 pushed view2, if I want to call any view1 method from view2. Is it possible. Is it a good practice.

TIA

Comment: It is normal practice, for example you can use "delegate" pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of structuring your app to handle it's in internal communication. The way you want to structure is up to you but it is necessary that you have basic knowledge in [object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and preferably also the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or other design patterns.

Here are a few examples on how you could structure your app:

**Suggestion 1**

> > - Create a class A and let your app create an instance of it.
> > - Let A create one instance of View1 and View2 each and keep a reference to them.
> > - Let View1 call a method in A, which in turn can call a method in View2.
> > - Let View2 call a method in A, which in turn can call a method in View1.

**Suggestion 2**

> > - Create an instance of View1 in your app
> > - Let View1 create an instance of View2 and keep a reference to it.
> > - Let View1 be delegate of View2
> > - View2 can call methods in View1 by calling its delegate, and View1 can call methods in View2 by calling the reference.

**Suggestion 3**

> > - Create some classes M1, M2 and M3 (a model describing your application)
> > - Create the Views View1 and View2.
> > - Create a controller class C
> > - Let View1 and View2 display the information in M1, M2 and M3
> > - When user interacts with View1 or View2, let them call methods in C, which in turn calls methods in M1, M2 and M3 changing their states.
> > - The changes in M1, M2 and M3 will be reflected by the information shown in View1 and View2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, actually there are several ways of doing that:

1. Use `delegate` pattern, as NeverBe suggested in comments (although you still need to pass the reference to caller)
2. Simply pass `View1` reference to `View2` upon creation, and use that reference later to call a method you need.
3. You can find the previous `viewController` on `NavigationController` stack, and call whatever public method it has available